# How are socket timeouts enforced in linux

Tags: sockets, network-programming

I'm trying to better understand how socket timeouts and keep-alive work in linux. This is the current snippet of code I'm using.

```py
import socket


def set_keepalive_linux(sock, after_idle_sec=1, interval_sec=3, max_fails=5):
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, after_idle_sec)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, interval_sec)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPCNT, max_fails)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
set_keepalive_linux(s)
s.connect(("www.python.org" , 80))
s.recv(1024)
```

Now, running netstat I see the timer set for this connection which makes sense.

```
tcp        0      0 myhost:randomport 199.232.44.223:http     ESTABLISHED 81658/python3        keepalive (0.88/0/0)
```

Now, if I replace this code with

```py
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  
s.settimeout(10)
s.connect(("www.python.org" , 80))
s.recv(1024)
```

I'm unable to see any timer set (I understand that the timer in `netstat -o` is specifically for keepalive/retransmission so `off` is the expected result on rerunning `netstat` but is it maintained elsewhere?). So my question would be, are socket timeouts expected to be implemented by the application and the kernel has nothing to do with it?

[[Edit 1]]
Seems like this is as expected for python. I've hacked together a C program from various parts of stackoverflow that does roughly the same. Would like to see if there's some way I can access the timeout information somewhere for this

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(void)
{
    int socket_desc;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    char server_message[2000], client_message[2000];
    
    // Clean buffers:
    memset(server_message,'\0',sizeof(server_message));
    memset(client_message,'\0',sizeof(client_message));
    
    // Create socket:
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    
    if(socket_desc < 0){
        printf("Unable to create socket\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    printf("Socket created successfully\n");
    
    // Set port and IP the same as server-side:
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("199.232.44.223");

    struct timeval timeout;      
    timeout.tv_sec = 10;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    
    if (setsockopt (socket_desc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &timeout,
                sizeof timeout) < 0)
        error("setsockopt failed\n");

    if (setsockopt (socket_desc, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, &timeout,
                sizeof timeout) < 0)
        error("setsockopt failed\n");
    
    // Send connection request to server:
    if(connect(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0){
        printf("Unable to connect\n");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Connected with server successfully\n");
    
    // Receive the server's response:
    if(recv(socket_desc, server_message, sizeof(server_message), 0) < 0){
        printf("Error while receiving server's msg\n");
        return -1;
    }
    
    printf("Server's response: %s\n",server_message);
    
    // Close the socket:
    close(socket_desc);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [A note about socket timeouts](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket-timeouts). It seems [`settimeout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout) is handled internally by Python and the socket module itself, and is unrelated to the standard socket timeouts.

Comment: Interesting. So I'm guessing this is the same behaviour when setting SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO according to the https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html? The timeouts are maintained by the application and does not involve the OS?

Comment: No, `SO_RCVTIMEO` and `SO_SNDTIMEO` are low-level timeouts handled in the TCP/IP stack itself, not by the application.

Comment: I see. Then would you know where / how I'd be able to confirm this timeout value? I've updated the question with a similar C program.

Comment: While I don't know the actual implementation (which should be easy to check, Python is open-source after all) my reading of the `settimeout` function and the timeout description makes it seem like they're using something like `select` to poll for activity, with a timeout passed to `select`. You should probably check the source for the `socket` module to see what `settimeout` really does.

Comment: Sorry I think I was a little unclear there. You mentioned `SO_RCVTIMEO` and `SO_SNDTIMEO` were low-level timeouts handled in the TCP/IP stack itself. So would that mean that the kernel would keep track of timers for timeouts in this scenario? If so, would it be possible to get the timeout value remaining for a particular connection like how I am able to get this value for keep-alive using netstat.

Comment: @saiyamansayspanic "*would it be possible to get the timeout value remaining for a particular connection*" - I've never seen anything that provides that kind of information.